# Why do I use a command defined in newcommand but still receive an error of undefined controlling sequences?

Tags: environments

Why do I use a command defined in newcommand but still receive an error of undefined controlling sequences?

I defined

`\newcommand\cutv[1]{\vspace{-5pt}\begin{align}#1\end{align}}`.

So why does it occur???

Comment: Are you loading the `amsmath` package for the `align` environment? What's the full error message? Without more information (like a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that?noredirect=1&lq=1)) we can only guess what's happening.

Comment: if asking about an error, show the exact error message from the log and show a complete example that produces the error. you have not shown which command is undefined nor provided an example. Please edit the question.